# How do you describe the situation where a person walks into tree twigs and the person following gets hit by them?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

What phrase or verb do you use to describe the situation where a person walks into tree twigs and the person following gets hit by them?

Comment: He bent the branches forward and then they sprang back and lashed the guy behind.

Comment: There isn't one fixed way of describing this situation, so you are free to invent your own.

Comment: Kate Bunting: I would appriciate it if you told me what you would say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may define such an incident to be a "***Twackening***"

I doubt that the word "***Twackening***" is in the Oxford English dictionary, but it might be; I did not check.

Twackenings likely occur as ***accidents***. Usually, people do not intend for the twigs to hit the person behind them. That is something which matters to me. I personally don't like it when others intentionally cause me harm.

You asked for a verb or phrase, but "***accident***" is a noun. I apologize for providing a noun such as "***accident***" instead of a verb or phrase.

"***Twackening***" is a gerund. I am not sure if gerunds are verbs. I always disliked words for parts of speech. When I am given a passage of mildly *skewey* English I can usually re-write the text so that it sounds more like what I have heard other people say or it looks like what I have seen other people write.  "*skewey*" is also not a word I often hear other people use. My mother often used the word "***scroogey***"

Let "*skewey*" be an adjective defined to be an alias of the term "***non-standard***" or "leaning". It originates from "skew" or "askew".

> Bob and Sarah were walking through the woods. The branches of the tree bent as Bob strode forward. As Bob took another step, the branches suddenly sprang back and lashed Sarah in the face. It was an accident.

A stack overflow user using the name [Bruce Murry](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/116645/bruce-murray) provided the phrase "they sprang back and lashed the guy behind."

By the way, I enjoy a lot of the movies in which  [Bill Murray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Murray) acted. For some reason, The name "Bruce Murry" reminded me of famous actor [Bill Murray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Murray).

---

In the field of mathematics, we would write something like the following:

> There existed **t** element of the set of all times, and there existed **p1** element of the set of all people, and there existed **p2** element of the set of all people and there existed a tree **t** element of the set of all trees such that **p1** walked into the branches of tree **t** and **p2** was following **p1** and **p1** got hit by the tree branches.

---

If you do not like my answer you are, of course, allowed to write your own answer and provide it as a more reasonable alternative.